# writing a function in R to produce multiple data frames and counting the data

Tags: r, computer-science, bioinformatics

1. Sample 20 people from our weight-height data. (weight-
   height.csv.gz)
   Count the number of males and females.  Repeat this a few times.
   a) Use chi-square test to accept/reject the null hypothesis that
   half of the population in the weight-height dataset is men.
   b) Repeat for a sample of 40, 60, 80 and 100 people

```
wh <- read.csv("weight-height.csv",header=TRUE)

iterations =10

output <- list()

for(i in 1:iterations){
    output[[i]] <- (sample_n(wh, 20, fac = "Gender"))
}
output
```

The output gives me 10 different data frame but I need help with creating a code that counts 'male' and 'female' from each data frame and then puts it in a new data frame that would look like this

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to do your homework *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve problems you encounter whilst *doing it for yourself*. "You must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself. The question must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." For more detail, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing the use of loops in R is a general good practice.  Here is some sample code with a toy data set.

```
set.seed(7)
data <- sample(c('F', 'M'), replace = TRUE, 1000)

iter <- 10
size <- 20    
samples <- replicate(iter, sample(data, size))
male_counts <- apply(samples, 2, function(x) sum(x == "M"))
female_counts <- size - male_counts
df <- data.frame(male_counts, female_counts)
df
   male_counts female_counts
1           12             8
2            8            12
3            9            11
4            7            13
5           11             9
6           11             9
7           13             7
8           14             6
9            8            12
10          11             9
```

The `replicate` function generates the samples and stores them as matrix.  The `apply` function sums the males across the samples columns and returns a vector.  The dataframe is simply constructed from the count vectors.